# Audacity records only 1 channel, inspite of being set to stereo

Tags: audio-recording, editing, daw, audacity

I use a Shure condenser mic with a Focusrite scarlett solo interface.  However ever since the 1st time I connected it to the laptop , & recorded in Audacity & mixpad, It keeps recording only 1 channel, inspite of settings adjusted to Stereo

see this image - (CONDENSER MIC )
[image]

[image: Recording thru computer mic]

Inspite of setting to Stereo it records like this . Would any of you know what can be the problem?  I have checked all connections - all are fine. Is this a problem with the xlr cable?

Comment: You've one mic, connected to 1 channel of a 2 channel input device. That's what I'd expect to see. Why do you need to record a mono source across 2 channels anyway? Twice the processing for no gain.

Comment: @Tetsujin,  usually when, I record through the built in mic in my computer, it records & shows on both channels. Y is this happening only when I connect my condenser mic?  Ideally it shouldnt happen

Comment: the built-in mic input is mono, the Focurite isn't.

Comment: @Tetsujin , I added another image please take a look at my question.  the built-in mic being mono, it records both channels , but with the focusrite it only records left channel

Comment: Correct - exactly as expected.

Comment: @Tetsujin , wait so you said the Focusrite isn't MONO rite, but the comp mic is? so that means that the focusrite should record both channels, right?

Comment: it has 2 channels, you're only using one. I still don't know **why** you want a mono recording across 2 channels. Makes no sense to me. & the Focusrite is, of course, recording both channels... just you have no sound going into one of them...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18899/discussion-between-stan-and-tetsujin).

Comment: When you say you're using the built-in mic your actually using the built-in audio interface for your computer which has a mono input for the mic. That's why it appears as you see (technically mono is the same exact sound spread over however many channels you mix it into). Hopefully this clears up some confusion.

Comment: @DoritoStyle, yes thanks, cleared up everything ! all working well now !

Comment: Isn't the stereo track used for cut/copy-pasting of voice and music or sound effects? That's what I use it for, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, this is the expected behavior.  Your computer mic input is a stereo mic jack that takes signal from the mono mic on both channels by nature of the connector design.  (On a mono 1/8" connector, the ring contact will touch the sleeve of a mono connector.)

Your Focusrite on the other hand has two distinct inputs, not a L/R configuration.  One mono input comes from the XLR, the other comes from the 1/4" jack.  You are incorrectly configuring it as a stereo recording when it is actually two distinct channels of mono audio.  Your recording records the lack of input on the second channel as you have nothing running in to it.

This is correct, expected and desired behavior.  There is no reason to record "in stereo" when both tracks would be identical.  You can pan a mono source however you feel like for producing a stereo image in the final output.  You don't have to capture as stereo to make stereo output and most recordings are initially captured in mono.  (Some exceptions include things like keyboards that may have their own stereo effects that the recording should capture.)

Comment: thanks ! I sorted it out a few days ago. I was confused initially .

Answer (score 0):

Is your condenser mic a stereo mic? If not, then there is absolutely no point of sending the same data to two channels. Your default computer mic might be a stereo mic which is why it automatically detects two signals. If your condenser mic is stereo and you have two XLR cables connected to the interface, you should check the focusrite mixer settings. There is a possibility that you might have to change how things are being routed.